# Can the search as you type behavior in the Mac OS X Spotlight feature be disabled?

Tags: macos, mac, spotlight

The goal is to invoke the spotlight search field, enter text and to generate search results only AFTER hitting enter. Default behavior is to start generating results as soon as a character is entered which creates sluggish performance on older Macs. Should be noted this refers to OS X versions prior to Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks like it may be no longer under development, have a look at [Laserlight](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/18364), a small utility for exactly that purpose

Comment: This is a handy app, thanks. Feels a little shaky and is not being updated. But still a good solution.